# Socket program in C for connecting two clients with same IP with a single server

Tags: c, sockets, client-server

When two clients with same IP try connecting to server only one will get connection. I want to check when the server will reply back to the client IP.

Will both clients( because they have same IP) receive the server reply, which could be security issue?

Comment: If two computers have the same address on a network, it simply will not work properly. Both hosts will receive the responses and one of them will reset the connection since it did not send the original packets.

Comment: 'When two clients with same IP try connecting to server only 1 will get connection.'???  What???  NO!

Comment: I don't understand.  On my test box, I have a server and 16 clients, all running tests, all on localhost/127.0.0.1.  No problem at all.  The clients are on different ports.  Works just fine.

Comment: Owait... . you mean two nodes with the same IP..  yeah, your network is a notwork.

Comment: You should edit your question to emphasize that you mean two client instances running on different boxes with the same IP.  This is a software site, and 'client' does not automatically mean 'computer box' to me, it means a client socket connection.

Comment: TCP is not secure anyway.  We know this, hence https etc.

Comment: For example if one client machine sends a DNS request to a server, and later another client machine spoofs the same IP and sends another DNS requuest, will the second client also receive response. Also when DNS responses to the IP, should both get response..